# Crystal Report with ODBC to MySQL Login Failed

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports, odbc

I am trying to connect Crystal Reports to ODBC for MySql.
I followed this article 
http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4870

It always ends with database login failed. 
Here is my code:

```
private void genReportBulananMaterialPasir(string[] param)
    {
        ViewSummaryMaterialPasir report = new ViewSummaryMaterialPasir();

        //Get SQL Server Details
        string zServer = server;
        string zDatabase = database;
        string zUsername = uid;
        string zPassword = password;

        ConnectionInfo ciReportConnection = new ConnectionInfo();

        ciReportConnection.ServerName = zServer;
        ciReportConnection.DatabaseName = zDatabase;
        ciReportConnection.UserID = "ROOT";
        ciReportConnection.Password = "12345";           

        //Assign data source details to tables

        foreach (Table table in report.Database.Tables)
        {
            table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ciReportConnection;
            table.ApplyLogOnInfo(table.LogOnInfo);
        }

        foreach (ReportDocument subrep in report.Subreports)
        {
            foreach (Table table in subrep.Database.Tables)
            {
                table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ciReportConnection;
                table.ApplyLogOnInfo(table.LogOnInfo);
            }
        }

        //Assign data source details to the report viewer
        if (this.crystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo != null)
        {
            TableLogOnInfos tlInfo = this.crystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo;
            foreach (TableLogOnInfo tbloginfo in tlInfo)
            {
                tbloginfo.ConnectionInfo = ciReportConnection;
            }
        }

        //String formula = "{tx_materialpasir.status} >=0 ";
        //"and {tx_materialpasir.tanggal} like '%" + param[0] + "' " +
        //"and {tx_materialpasir.konsumen} = " + param[1] + " " +
        //"and {tx_materialpasir.plant} = " + param[2] +"";


        report.SetDatabaseLogon
          ("ROOT", "12345");
        report.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["sPeriode"].Text = "'" + periode(param[0]) + "'";
        //crystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = formula;

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();

    }
```

Comment: If you use the mysql client to connect to that server/db with the given credentials (hopefully the username and password are fake in your question) does that work?

Comment: @rene yes, i am using the same username and password for my application connection.

Comment: @rene i use the same function to connect MSSQL server no problem happen.

Comment: Hi @user3424580 did you solve the problem? for i'm also facing it

Comment: I forgot did i solve it or not, so i will close this case ok.